# Does System.Data.OracleClient support oracle 11g?

Tags: c#, database, oracle

Does System.Data.OracleClient support oracle 11g? If yes which version? The .Net appplication is presently running on 32bit server. We will be upgrading to 64 bit. Will System.Data.OracleClient support 64 bit too? Version of System.Data.OracleClient in use at present 2.0.0.0 with oracle 9i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult question, according to this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/457811/oracle-data-provider-support-for-oracle-11g) it does not and it will not in the future either. However, I'm currently using `System.Data.OracleClient` to connect to an 64bit 11g server and I've got Oracle's 11g client tools installed and I have no problems.

Comment: What are you using oracle client for? Are you sure you are not using ODP.Net

Comment: @Prithis - I probably wrote that a bit confusingly. I use MS client, but I also have ODP.Net and the rest of Oracle's 11g client tools installed. I just mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: I can confirm that System.Data.OracleClient works with oracle 11g. I have version 2.0 of the dll. But as Daniel has correctly suggested looking forward we should use ODP.net.

Answer (score 1):

System.Data.OracleClient will be deprecated soon. If you think about future you better go on this one [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html)

Comment: Also I remember that there was some update of .net 3.5 sp1 that must resolve this problem.